# how to display the correct image when sharing to facebook, Facebook open graph meta

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

[Here](http://www.woolito.com/about-%E9%97%9C%E6%96%BC%E7%84%A1%E5%8E%98%E9%A0%AD/) I have set a image url by the `og:image` tag, but when sharing to the facebook, it doesn't show the correct image that I just set, instead it shows lots of images that doesn't appear in that page.

I've tried to enter the URL [on the Facebook debugging system](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), but it shows no errors.

Comment: here's your OG debug: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.woolito.com%2Fabout-%25E9%2597%259C%25E6%2596%25BC%25E7%2584%25A1%25E5%258E%2598%25E9%25A0%25AD%2F which shows no issues - and this image is being correctly pulled from that page. No bug? http://image.woolito.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/woolito_people-200x200.jpg

Comment: There's no bug in OG debug, but when sharing to the facebook, it shows lots of images which are not the image i set before, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is it resolved? I have set an image as og:image, while sharing from sharethis tool it is sharing correct image but when I am sharing directly on my wall or in message, it is showing incorrect images.